# What way can I validate element contains text without failing test when the same element contains different text?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a scnearios where an element on a table changes from one text for example 'staging..' to a date for example today's date '10/03/2023'. It doesn't change automatically so you would have to click on a apply button to see it is changed or not and it takes around 30 / 40 seconds to change. I want to check every 8 seconds by clicking Apply button that the column changes from 'staging' to today's date.

So I have implemented a code like below -

[image]

The code works OK in terms of keep clicking Apply button every 8 secs. However, it fails due to the assertion -cy.get('td').eq(1).contains(`Staging...`) changes.

Is there any way I can avoid the assertion and check this condition so the it doesn't fail?

Many thanks in advace :)

Comment: Is there a way for you to check it in the backend before it reflects on the UI?

Comment: I think the way would be to check it via API which wouldn't be strainghtforward due to some other conditions related to it. Also by doing this in the UI will mimic how the website is used.

Comment: If the API was more straight forward you could recurse until it was shown there first and then check the UI afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [cypress-recurse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-recurse) to handle your recursion in Cypress.

The API is a bit tricky, the summary is

- first parameter is a selector only, it cannot have implicit assertion like `.contains()` or the recursion will fail on first iteration
- second parameter is the assertion you need to be true
- your `else` code can go into the optional `post` callback

```js
recurse(
  () => cy.get(selector).first().find('td').eq(1),   // this part is just selecting,
                                                      // no assertion here

  ($td) => $td.text() !== 'Staging...',               // assertion here, 
                                                      // recurses if fails

  // after recursion run the post function
  {
    postLastValue: true,                              // $td after staging is passed
                                                      // into post: as value

    post: ({ value, success }) => {                   
      cy.wrap(value).should('contain', todayDate)     // confirm text after change
    }
  }
})
```

If you invert the logic, you can remove the `post`,

```js
cy.get(selector).first().find('td').first().should('contain', 'Staging...')

recurse(
  () => cy.get(selector).first().find('td').eq(1),  
  ($td) => $td.text() === todayDate,                 // repeat until true
)
```

---

**Reproducable example**

Run this HTML on a local server

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First column</td>
      <td>Staging...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const td = document.querySelector('td')
    td.innerText = '...Finished'
  },2000)
</script>
```

This is the (similar) test

```js
cy.get('tr').first().find('td').eq(1)
  .should('contain', 'Staging...')

recurse(
  () => cy.get('tr').first().find('td').eq(1),  
  ($td) => $td.text() === '...Finished',               
)
```

This is the log

[image]

Comment: The text doesn't change automatically. Is it possible to click a button within recurse? recurse( () => cy.get(applybutton).click(),cy.get(selector).first().find('td').eq(1), ($td) => $td.text() === todayDate,  )
Also how do you configure the number of recursion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of recursion and the yielded JQuery elements to accomplish this.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('isElementUpdated', (selector, retry = 0) => {
  // We'll always check if it contains 'Staging...'
  cy.get(selector).first().within(() => {
    // Yield the element that may or may not contain 'Staging...'
    cy.get('td').eq(1).then(($el) => {
      // Check if element contains 'Staging...'
      // If retry is at the maximum, we won't run this and instead will just validate the date
      if ($el.text().includes('Staging...' && retry < 10) {
        cy.wait(8000);
        cy.get('ApplyButton').click({ force: true });
        cy.isElementUpdated(selector, retry + 1);
      }
    }
  });
  cy.get(selector)
    .should('be.visible')
    .first()
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('td').eq(1).should('contain', todaysDate);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't quite work. Rather retrying, it's going to validate - cy.get('td').eq(1).should('contain', todaysDate). I tried changing $el.text() == 'Staging...' then it seems validating but again within that selector - cy.get('ApplyButton').click({ force: true }); the apply button is not found.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want your test to fail on cy.contains() you can integrate conditional testing:

```
cy.get(selector).first().then(
    ($selector) => {
    if ($selector.text() === "Something 1") {
    // Do everything you want here
}
else if {$selector.text() === "Something 2"} {
    // Do everything you want here
}
else {
    // Do everything you want here
}
}
```

Comment: Tried below but the retry goes on 10 times even text changed -
function isElementVisible() {

if ( retry < 10 &&
cy. .get(selector).first().within(() => {
cy.get('td')
.eq(1)
.then((elem) => {
 elem.text() === 'Staging...' })
})) {
retry++
cy.wait(8000)
 cy.get(applybutton).click({ force: true })
cy.then(isElementVisible)
} else if (
retry < 10 &&
cy
.get(selector)
.first()
.within(() => {
 cy.get('td')
 .eq(1)
 .then((elem) => {
elem.text() === 'Processed...'
 })
 })
 ) { do something }